# Does a media folder in asp.net application get loaded for each user

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have a media folder with about 1GB of data that I added to my Web Application. When a user starts a session, is the media copied for each user?
Should I be putting the Media folder outside the application folder?

```
Solution 'TestApp'
>  TestApp
   My Project
>  Media  ...(folder with about 1 gb of data)       
   Default.aspx
   Global.asax
   jquery-1.4.1.min.js
   Web.Config
```

Comment: media folder? Is it some speacial folder I haven't heard or just a regular folder with bunch of images and videos?

Comment: Not a special folder, it contains images, .htm documents, etc..

Comment: as i tried to answer. you dont have to put media folder outside of application.  but using another domain name static.yoursite.com is also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know  any special folder called as media folder

. All resources is in this folder will be served to user whomever demanded. With caching capabilities of IIS and web browser all content might not be even served twice.

So simply : No! the content of media folder is not loaded to memory for each   sessions.

By default IIS directly serves static content.

https://serverfault.com/questions/255849/iis-7-5-optimizations-for-a-site-serving-only-static-content

http://www.ckode.dk/server-configuration/tuning-iis-7-for-static-content/

Comment: Thanks, so basically i can leave the folder with all the media within in the project

Comment: http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/ maybe you might want to serve static content from another cookie-less sub domain.